# Default List pages (NewForm.aspx/EditForm.aspx) and breadcrumbs

Tags: master-page, application-pages, list-form, breadcrumb, ghosting

All,

My understanding of SharePoint is that NewForm.aspx/EditForm.aspx et al. are Application Pages that for each List are initially fetched from the Hive directly and processed by ASP.NET, but can be un-ghosted and modified per-List instance using SharePoint designer?

I have a client who wishes to have the breadcrumb trail at the top of all instances of the List/Library pages (NewForm.aspx/EditForm.aspx).

If my first statement is correct Application Pages and that I have two options:

1. Go into the Hive and change the Templates for those files to reference the new MasterPage using @Page/@MasterPage directive to ~master/something.aspx. Obviously, this is not a good idea but makes the changes work for every List created.
2. Use SharePoint Designer to un-ghost and modify each set of templates per-List instance. This makes each List slower and needs to be done every time.

Am I overlooking something. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Thanks,

Michael Taylor